# Request parameter RefreshType is not in correct format

Tags: json, azure, httprequest, azure-logic-apps

I try to process my Azure Analysis Service Cube via logic APP:

[image]

In HTTP action I have the following body:

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "method": "POST",
        "uri": "https://northeurope.asazure.windows.net/servers/xxx/models/xxx/refreshes",
        "body": {
            "refresh": {
                "objects": [
                    {
                        "database": "ModelName",
                        "table": "TableName"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "full"
            }
        },
        "authentication": {
            "type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth",
            "authority": "https://login.windows.net",
            "tenant": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
            "audience": "https://*.asazure.windows.net",
            "clientId": "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "secret": "xxxxYjxx7y5xxskHxxxxxxznxxxxxxxxODX+xxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

After runningthis logic app, I get the following error:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "headers": {
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=xxxxxx00; includeSubDomains",
        "x-ms-root-activity-id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx",
        "x-ms-current-utc-date": "2/7/2019 9:25:05 AM",
        "x-ms-xmlaerror-extended": "Request parameter RefreshType is not in correct format.",
        "Date": "Thu, 07 Feb 2019 09:25:05 GMT",
        "Server": "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
        "Content-Length": "294",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    "body": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "subCode": 2,
        "message": "Request parameter RefreshType is not in correct format.",
        "timeStamp": "2019-02-07T09:25:05.4650388Z",
        "httpStatusCode": 400,
        "details": [
            {
                "code": "RootActivityId",
                "message": "353ab74e-2793-4ee5-954f-819c851f4cb6"
            },
            {
                "code": "Param1",
                "message": "RefreshType"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Do you have any Idea, why I get this error message? and How can I solve this problem

Comment: Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

Refresh Type is an ENUM which only takes values from below list, Can you make the type to Full and check if works:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have changed it to `"type": 1` but still get the same error

Comment: No i meant, have you tried with Full with proper casing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to remove the "refresh" node, so the body looks like this:

```
"body": {
   "objects": [
      {
         "database": "ModelName",
         "table": "TableName"
      }
   ],
   "type": "full"
},
```

I hope this helps.